# Enabling postmortem debugging on Windows 10

Tags: debugging, windows-10, postmortem-debugging

With older Windows versions, when an unhandled exception occurred in an application, the user was given a choice of running a postmortem debugger and possibly resolving the exception. It was even possible to set up a postmortem debugger to start automatically (e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging). However, it seems this functionality has either been removed completely or at least disabled in Windows 10 - the failing application will silently terminate and the only trace of the error is the record written into the event log. Is there any way of getting the old behavior back? Is it something my application needs to do (e.g. to register itself as a possible target of a postmortem debugger) or it is something system-related?

Answer (score 0):

One year later, I had to reinstall a postmortem debugger which was working on a win7 system on a win10... and it worked.

So I don't think there are limitations for win10 in this scenario, worked in my machine :)